# D3, plotting to map, possible data formatting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a map and plot some points to it using d3, I found a few good examples to build off of but I believe i am stuck. My guess is I am not handling the plot points correctly according to how I have the data structured. I could use a bit of help - this is my first attempt. Here's what I have so far :

```
 var m_width = document.getElementById("map").offsetWidth,
width = 938,
height = 500;

 var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale(150)
.translate([width / 2, height / 1.5]);

 var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

 var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
.attr("width", m_width)
.attr("height", m_width * height / width);

 svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "background")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)


var g = svg.append("g");

 d3.json("scripts/world-110m2.json", function(error, us) {
g.append("g")
.attr("id", "countries")
.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.countries).features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
.attr("d", path)

});

svg.selectAll(".pin")
.data(places)
.enter().append("circle", ".pin")
.attr("r", 5)
.attr("transform", function(d) {
 return "translate(" + projection([
  d.earthquakes.lon,
  d.earthquakes.lat
]) + ")"
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
var w = document.getElementById("map").offsetWidth;
svg.attr("width", w);
svg.attr("height", w * height / width);
  });
```

And the "places" data is structured like so

```
 var places = {"count":"392","earthquakes":[{"src":"us","eqid":"2010sdbk","timedate":"2010-01-31 15:18:44","lat":"-18.7507","lon":"169.3940","magnitude":"5.1","depth":"231.50","region":"Vanuatu"}
```

Where all the place are inside an object array "earthquakes" inside places. (lon and lat specifically inside of that).

The world map shows up fine, I am just having trouble getting these plot points to work. Would appreciate any help greatly. Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, but couple problems here:

1.) The data you pass to `.data` should be an array (of where to add your circles).

2.) In your `places` object, you lat/lon are strings and need to be converted to numbers.

Try:

```
var places = {
   "count": "392",
   "earthquakes": [{
     "src": "us",
     "eqid": "2010sdbk",
     "timedate": "2010-01-31 15:18:44",
     "lat": "-18.7507",
     "lon": "169.3940",
     "magnitude": "5.1",
     "depth": "231.50",
     "region": "Vanuatu"
   }]
 };

 svg.selectAll(".pin")
   .data(places.earthquakes) //<-- pass array
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class","pin")
   .attr("r", 5)
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + projection([
       +d.lon, //<-- coerce to number
       +d.lat
     ]) + ")";
   });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4YguGV1HInKUcFBGylDk?p=info).